# JSON for popuplate HTML div

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to use an JSON string to popolate an html div, here's my code, but it seems not working, I still cannot realize why, there's some suggestions?

The JSON is created via PHP and it is working fine.
Thank you.

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    var Currencies = function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"js/php/users.php",
            success:function(data){
                return{
                    getMyJson: function(data){
                        return(data);
                    }
                }
            }
        });     
    }(); // execute the function when the MyObj variable is initialized.   
});
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: Currencies.getMyJson(),
    onSelect: function (suggestion){
        var thehtml = '<strong>Currency Name:</strong> ' + suggestion.nome + ' <br> ';
        $('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
    }
});
```

Comment: you can't do that... returning a value from an async method like an ajax call... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: slightly offtopic, but http://rog.ie/blog/dugjs-a-jsonp-to-html-script is a very clean solution to populating html with json data

Answer (score 1):

Few observations

- The `Currencies` object is local to the dom ready handler, so it is not accessible outside it. Move your `autocomplete` plugin initialization inside the dom ready handler.
- You can't return a value from a asynchronous method like that - See [How to return the response from an AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Try

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var Currencies = {
        getMyJson: function (callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "js/php/users.php",
                success: function (data) {
                    callback(data)
                }
            });
        }
    }; // execute the function when the MyObj variable is initialized.   

    Currencies.getMyJson(function (data) {
        $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
            lookup: data,
            onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                var thehtml = '<strong>Currency Name:</strong> ' + suggestion.nome + ' <br> ';
                $('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Arun P Johny but is not working i checked the output writing alert(data) after callback(data) the alert is correct

Comment: @Priya can you add a alert() before `$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({` and see whether it is getting called

Comment: I did it, the output is correct too...
Still cannot realize why i doesen't work <.<

Comment: @Priya if you gives a static data as the lookup value whether it is working

Answer (score 0):

move this code

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: Currencies.getMyJson(),
    onSelect: function (suggestion){
        var thehtml = '<strong>Currency Name:</strong> ' + suggestion.nome + ' <br> ';
        $('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
    }
});
```

into

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
```